# Testing against early returns (defensive programming)

Tags: unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I am learning testing and trying to test a function using 'early returns'. The function on success sets a property in another class and on failure simply returns so in both cases it 'returns' void.

```
class Test
{
    private $fileHandler;
    private $config;

    public __constructor($fileHandler, $config)
    {
        $this->fileHandler = $fileHandler;
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function example($filePath)
    {
        $exists = $this->fileHandler->exists($filePath);

        if ($exists === false) {
             return;
        }

        $this->config->set($filePath);
    }
}
```

In this example I *believe* I can test this with two unit tests and by mocking the `fileHandler` class.

For a failure (early return) the `$config` class's method `set()` should not be called whilst for a success the method should be called.

However, this test passes if I try and change `never()` to `once()` making me think the entire test is bogus.

```
/** test */
public function config_is_not_set_with_missing_file()
{
    $fileHandlerMock = $this->getMockBuilder(fileHandler::class)->getMock;
    $fileHandlerMock->method('exists')
        ->willReturn('false');
    $configMock = $this->getMockBuilder(config::class)->getMock;

    $test = new Test($fileHandlerMock, $configMock);
    $test->example('fake file path');

    $configMock->expects($this->never())
        ->method('set');
}
```

Comment: not sure if that is the reason but you should configure the mock before executing the `$test->example()` sentence

Comment: Careful! `'false' !== false`! Your mocked function returns a string with the contents "false", not a boolean *false*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file handler mock is returning the string `'false'`, which is `!==` to `false`. Change that to `false` and `Tets::example` should return early.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the `$configMock` to the `Test` constructor, so it's not being used.

You're right, if the test passes both with `once` and `never` expectations, the test is not working as expected and requires reviewing it.

Comment: try what I stated in my comment: configure the mock before executing the `example` method